# What is the best way to handle Autocomplete with a million of records efficiently?

Tags: jpa, autocomplete, large-data

I've just started doing some Java  EE projects right now I'm trying to update my existing auto complete field. I'm using Primeface for JSF, and I'm using JPA.

My auto complete is working fine. My problem now is that the records have grown to a million and with that my current code is now producing an out of memory/heap space problem due to the large List generated.

I generate the List on ejb with @Startup since the data does not change. It just usually grow when we add more data directly to the database. Also when I try loading this to a Managed Bean with a @Postconstruct I get the out of memory faster.

I'm using this to populate my list in the ejb

```
private List<TranslationAutoComplete> translations;    

this.translations = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.sample.model.TranslationAutoComplete(t.id, t.entry) FROM Translation t ORDER BY t.entry ASC", TranslationAutoComplete.class).getResultList();
```

With that what can be the better structure for me to efficiently handle this without producing some memory/ heap space problem? I've read about Memcache? and other non java core Colletions but haven't tried it yet. Are these the better solution? Or is there a more efficient way in doing this in Java EE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to limit the query results. You can achieve this with the `setMaxResults(int maxResults)` for your [Query](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html). If you do this:

```
this.translations = em
   .createQuery("SELECT NEW com.sample.model.TranslationAutoComplete(t.id, t.entry) 
      FROM Translation t ORDER BY t.entry ASC", TranslationAutoComplete.class)
        .setMaxResults(10).getResultList();
```

You will get only 10 results. If the user keeps inputting data on your autocomplete, then more results will appear, making it a lot more efficient. Cheers.

Comment: This answer led me to the most efficient way of doing auto complete. So what I did was I added the String query parameter on this method and also added the "LIKE =: entry" in the query, then added .setParameter("entry", query + "%") together with the setMaxResults(10). This changed the way I was creating the auto complete because I was following the Primeface example which loads all results then do the filtering with .startsWith() inside the Managed Bean method.

Answer (score 0):

First just go through `Jprofiler` and check which specific data is cause of `outOfMemoryException`. It might be possible that some other `Objects` like number of connection taking a lots of memory resource.

The large data is realy like a time bomb for managed bean. As I prefer load only fixed limit of record in List of your `@Postconstruct` initially and fetch required record in diffrent service request(if there is million of records).

You can also increase the Run time memory space of your application server but this is not logical and not a good approach to handle this problem.